# Paypal returns API credentials are incorrect

Tags: php, api, paypal, credentials, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been fighting this issue for five days now. It is an enigma to me. Can anybody find out why this code returns error52003, API credentials are incorrect? Your help or fresh view is much appreciated.

```
<?php

$USER_ID="userid";
$USER_PASS="userpass";
$USER_SIG="usersig";
$APP_ID="appid";

$apiUrl="https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";

$headers = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".$USER_ID,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".$USER_PASS,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".$USER_SIG,
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".$APP_ID,
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON"
);

$createPacket = array (
    "actionType"=>"PAY",
    "currencyCode"=>"EUR",
    "receiverList"=> array (
        "receiver"=> array(
            array(
                "amount"=> "1",
                "email"=>"merchant1@someemail.sk"
            ),
            array(
                "amount"=> "2",
                "email"=>"merchant2@someemail.sk"
            )
        )
    ),
    "returnUrl"=>"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/",
    "cancelUrl"=>"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/",
    "requestEnvelope"=>array(
        "errorLanguage"=>"en_US"
    )
);


$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($createPacket));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array($headers));

    $result= curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
```

?>

Comment: You shouldn't share your API credentials in a public place like this website. If you are sure that those values are correct you can just hide them and assume that the problem is in some other place

Comment: if you are sending POST fields with cURL you should also set the flag that "tells" the library that you are doing it, like this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: Good to point things like that out, Mishu. These credentials are standard paypal credentials they are providing for testing purposes. Feel free to try this code. I added the line you mentioned but it didn't help.Any other ideas?

Comment: Did it work correctly six days ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array($headers));
```

should be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Hey Matt, I am giving you a tick because it really is a mistake. However, still not working. Same old mistake. There must be something else. Can you see anything?

Comment: Revised my solution.  Don't throw `$headers` into an array -- it's already an array.

Comment: SUCCESS!!! I have lost five days of my life but this message was worth it! You made it! Thank heavens for wizards like you. God bless all your houses. Thank you